# List of changed components in a workspace snapshot

Tags: rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

Using the "scm.exe" utility commands, it is possible to list the changed components using snapshot UUID?

[I can get list of components](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYMRC_6.0.2/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/list_components.html), and 
[I can get list of changes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYMRC_6.0.2/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/list_changes.html)

But really can't find a way to get "list of changed components" within a given snapshot.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A snapshot is a static thing, it does not contain any notion of any previous state or snapshot.  When you say "changed components", the question is really: changed compared to what?

You should be able to use the [compare](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYMRC_6.0.2/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/compare.html) command to see what is different between the snapshot and either a second snapshot, or some other workspace or stream.